# Add classifier next to its group in PCA ggplot - R

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I added the Species classifier next to the centroid in this PCA plot.

Code:

```
library(ggpubr)
library(ggbiplot)

data(iris)
Species<- iris$Species

myPCA <- prcomp(iris[.1:4], scale. = TRUE)

dt<-data.table(PC1=myPCA$x[,1],PC2=myPCA$x[,2],  Species)
dt[order(dt$Species),]
centeriod<-summaryBy(PC1+PC2 ~ Species, data=dt, FUN=list(mean))

ggplot(dt,aes(x=PC1,y=PC2,color=Species, fill=Species)) +  geom_point(size = 2)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would need the ggpubr and ggbiplot packages in this case. You can do this with just ggplot2 (and data.table which you already used in your example).

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

data(iris)
Species<- iris$Species

myPCA <- prcomp(iris[,1:4], scale. = TRUE)

dt <- data.table(PC1=myPCA$x[,1],PC2=myPCA$x[,2],  Species)
dt <- dt[order(dt$Species),]

centeroid <- dt[, list(PC1 = mean(PC1), PC2 = mean(PC2)), by = Species]

ggplot(dt,aes(x=PC1,y=PC2)) +  
  geom_point(size = 2, aes(color=Species)) +
  geom_text(data = centeroid, aes(label = Species))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank. My error. Forgot the replace it with data.table. I add installation issue with ggbiplot

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry for answering again, but I was so bothered that I wasn't able to do this simply within ggplot that I wrote a stat to fix that. You can find it in the ggh4x package.

```r
library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.0.2
library(ggh4x)

data(iris)
Species<- iris$Species

myPCA <- prcomp(iris[,1:4], scale. = TRUE)

dt <- data.frame(PC1=myPCA$x[,1],PC2=myPCA$x[,2],  Species)

ggplot(dt,aes(x=PC1,y=PC2, group = Species)) +  
  geom_point(size = 2, aes(color=Species)) +
  stat_centroid(aes(label = Species), geom = "text")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>